# Loading a GML file to PostGIS using Python and GDAL vectortranslate: encoding problems

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I have some GML files I want to load into my PostGIS database using the GMLAS reader in GDAL in a Python script. The script is run from a batch file. For example this dataset from Geonorge - https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/metadata/grunnskoler/db4b872f-264d-434c-9574-57232f1e90d2.

I can import a GML file to my PostGIS database using ogr2ogr from the osgeo4w shell, and it goes smoothly, it does not complain about encoding and the Norwegian characters that are in table names and column names, and everything is imported correctly.

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=host port=port dbname=dbname user=user password=pass" GMLAS:"<path to gml>" -nlt CONVERT_TO_LINEAR -lco SCHEMA=output_schema
```

However, when I try to do the same with `gdal.VectorTranslate` in a Python script, I get problems with encoding. `"invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8":"`

```
srcDS = gdal.OpenEx('GMLAS:path_to_gml', gdal.OF_VECTOR, ) 

gdal.VectorTranslate(
        postgisDS, 
        srcDS,  
        format = 'PostgreSQL',
        geometryType = 'CONVERT_TO_LINEAR',
        layerCreationOptions=['SCHEMA=output_schema']
        )
```

My GML file says it is in UTF8, the first line is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Opening the file in Notepad++ and Notepad says the file is in UTF8.

My database has UTF8 encoding. I am doing this on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter machine using Python 3 and gdal installed from osgeo4w. Gdal version is 3.1.4 og Python is 3.7.

I have read of different posts and websites on this, and I cannot seem to get anything to work. I have tried setting PGCLIENTENCODING, and changing the codepage of the command line, and lots of other stuff. I am now very confused, and still can’t get it to work.

The script works fine on a Linux machine I have access to, but I need it to work on Windows.

Any ideas?